# Is it possible to list all possible user's roles with CASE statement from one table? [TERADATA]

Tags: sql, database, teradata

[image]

I am figuring out whether it is possible to list all 4 roles that user needs to have with 'Yes' or 'No' statement to each one. For example.

```
SELECT DISTINCT Grantee, GranteeKind, RoleName, WhenGranted,
    CASE
        WHEN RoleName='Manager' THEN 'Yes'
        WHEN RoleName='Assistant' THEN 'Yes'
        WHEN RoleName='Executive' THEN 'Yes'
        WHEN RoleName='Deputy' THEN 'Yes'
                    ELSE NULL
            END AS "Already granted?"
    FROM DBC.RolesM
    WHERE Grantee='UserName' 
    AND RoleName IN
    ('Manager',
    'Assistant',
    'Executive',
    'Deputy');
```

My query fetches the below result and it is 100 percent correct.

```
Grantee    GranteeKind  RoleName    WhenGranted Already Granted? 
UserName    User    Manager         2018-01-30        Yes
UserName    User    Assistant       2016-01-30        Yes
```

Nevertheless, I am wondering if it is possible to get something like this so we have explicit answer for the roles that are not assigned.

```
Grantee    GranteeKind  RoleName    WhenGranted Already Granted? 
UserName    User    Manager         2018-01-30        Yes
UserName    User    Assistant       2016-01-30        Yes
UserName    User    Executive       2016-01-30        No
UserName    User    Deputy          2016-01-30        No
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a `cross join` to generate the rows and then a `left join` to bring in the values.

Unfortunately, Teradata makes it a little difficult to generate the list of roles, but this should work:

```
select g.Grantee, g.GranteeKind, r.RoleName, 
       rm.WhenGranted,
       (case when rm.RoleName is not null then 'Yes' else 'No' end) as already_granted
from (select distinct grantee, GranteeKind
      from DBC.RolesM
     ) g cross join
     (select distinct RoleName
      from DBC.RolesM
      where RoleName in ('Manager', 'Assistant', 'Executive', 'Deputy')
     ) r left join
     DBC.RolesM rm
     on rm.grantee = g.grantee and rm.rolename = r.rolename
```

Answer (score 0):

Try query given as below hope this helps.

```html
SELECT  *
FROM    ( SELECT  Grantee, GranteeKind, RoleName, WhenGranted, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY RoleName ORDER BY id) AS RowNumber
    CASE
        WHEN RoleName='Manager' THEN 'Yes'
        WHEN RoleName='Assistant' THEN 'Yes'
        WHEN RoleName='Executive' THEN 'Yes'
        WHEN RoleName='Deputy' THEN 'Yes'
                    ELSE NULL
            END AS "Already granted?"
    FROM DBC.RolesM
    WHERE Grantee='UserName' 
    AND RoleName IN
    ('Manager',
    'Assistant',
    'Executive',
    'Deputy')) AS a
WHERE   a.RowNumber = 1
```

Comment: Thanks for your effort and help. As already mentioned in a second comment, the first query did the good job for me.

Comment: No worries, beware of OLAP queries - especially with large data sets. ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ... ORDER BY ...) will likely involve a redistribution and will absolutely involve a sort. If you are paying for TPerf (CPU usage), don't do OLAP functions unless you have to. Having said that, in this case, it shouldn't be too bad as the volumes will be low. In one example I benchmarked the OLAP function took more than 3 times the resources of an equivalent non-OLAP function.

You should accept and upvote the answer that works best for you.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have access to my TD right now, so I'm doing this from memory:

```sql
select Grantee, GranteeKind, RoleName,
    max(managerRole), max(AssistantRole), max(ExecutiveRole), max(DeputyRole)
from (
  SELECT DISTINCT Grantee, GranteeKind, RoleName, WhenGranted,
    CASE
        WHEN RoleName='Manager' THEN 'Yes' ELSE 'No'
    END as ManagerRole,
    CASE
        WHEN RoleName='Assistant' THEN 'Yes' ELSE 'No'
    END as AssistantRole,
    CASE
        WHEN RoleName='Executive' THEN 'Yes' ELSE 'No'
    END as ExecutiveRole,
    CASE
        WHEN RoleName='Deputy' THEN 'Yes' ELSE 'No'
    END AS DeputyRole
  FROM DBC.RolesM
  WHERE Grantee='UserName' 
    AND RoleName IN
    ('Manager',
    'Assistant',
    'Executive',
    'Deputy')
  ) as DT
group by 1, 2, 3
order by 1, 2;
```

hopefully there will be no syntax errors.

Basically the inner query produces a list like this:

```
Grantee etc, ManagerRole, AssistantRole, etc
abc,             Yes          No
abc,             No           Yes
def,             Yes          No
def,             No           No
```

Then the outer query selects the aggregate of each column. We are doing a max, so "Yes" will beat "No". You will only get a No if the user doesn't have the role.

Note: There is an assumption that the Grantee, GrantKind and RoleName are all the same. If they are not, you will get multiple records per Grantee. I've had to omit the "when Granted" because that will probably be at different times.

Comment: Thanks, quite interesting query as well and I think it may work too. Nevertheless, I found  the first one a bit better.